# using nextjs progress bar on Nextjs 13.3.1

Tags: next.js, next.js13

**How do I add the following nextjs code into the new nextjs's layout.tsx file?**

The file is a progress bar. The current documentation uses the app.js from previous versions of NextJS.

```
import NextNProgress from 'nextjs-progressbar';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <NextNProgress />
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
  );
}
```

this is what I tried

```
"use client"
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import NextNProgress from 'nextjs-progressbar';
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <NextNProgress></NextNProgress>
      {children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can your share what isn't working or why the implementation you have tried isn't suiting your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a solution now. This might be helpful for others.

"nextjs-progressbar" uses createContext which can't be used on server comonents by default. You may have a look [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components)

One more thing quoted from [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required) website of Good to know part "**The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component.**". [Image Snippet of Good to know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuwRE.png)

**Solution:**

1. You need to create a new client component holding NextNProgress.
2. Use that client component on the root layout.

**1. Custom Client Component**

```
'use client';
import NextNProgress from 'nextjs-progressbar';

const NextNProgressClient = () => {
    return <NextNProgress />;
};

export default NextNProgressClient;
```

**2. Root Layout**

```
import './globals.css';

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

import NextNProgressClient from '@/app/components/next-progress';

import type { Metadata } from 'next';
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'Create Next App',
    description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang='en'>
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <NextNProgressClient />
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully addressed the progress bar issue in my Next.js 14 app router. Here's a robust solution that effectively integrates a progress bar:

First Install: "nextjs-toploader": "^1.6.4".
Then import the package in your layout file. Here is the sample code:

```
'use client'
import { Inter as FontSans } from "next/font/google"
import "./globals.css"
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import NextTopLoader from 'nextjs-toploader';

export const fontSans = FontSans({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  variable: "--font-sans",
})

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <head />
      <body
        className={cn(
          "min-h-screen bg-background font-sans antialiased",
          fontSans.variable
        )}
      >
        <NextTopLoader
          color="orange"
          initialPosition={0.08}
          crawlSpeed={200}
          height={3}
          crawl={true}
          showSpinner={true}
          easing="ease"
          speed={200}
          shadow="0 0 10px #2299DD,0 0 5px #2299DD"
        />
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a new client component with "use client" and put in to it the   component then you can just call this component and wrap the children of layouts with it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use nextjs version 13:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next13-progressbar

Answer (score 0):

**You must use templates**

> Templates are similar to layouts in that they wrap each child layout
> or page. Unlike layouts that persist across routes and maintain state,
> templates create a new instance for each of their children on
> navigation. This means that when a user navigates between routes that
> share a template, a new instance of the component is mounted, DOM
> elements are recreated, state is not preserved, and effects are
> re-synchronized.

Create a file called `template.tsx` next to `layout.tsx` (in same level)

```
'use client'
import { AppProgressBar as ProgressBar } from 'next-nprogress-bar'
const Template = ({ children }: any) => {

   return (
      <>
        <NextNProgress/>
         {children}
      </>
   )
}

export default Template
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. I found one video which describes few things and after following those, loader is working fine

1. First create a component and use top loading bar component there. Declare that client component as you can't use client in layout.js or main app.js. Use pathname from next/navigation to display loading bar
2. Call that component in layout.js

This video might help.
https://youtu.be/RAi0mei_zTs?si=wpwNQEArjfzMtIBJ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a client layout component.

For example:

```
("use client");
import NextNProgress from "nextjs-progressbar";

interface ClientLayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const ClientLayout: React.FC<ClientLayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <NextNProgress />
      {children}
    </>
  );
};

export default ClientLayout;
```

but I suggest nextjs-toploader package. You can use it in layout.tsx. It doesn't need client layout

[npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-toploader)

Answer (score -2):

To add the progress bar code to the new Next.js layout file (`layout.tsx`), you can modify your existing code as follows:

```
// layout.tsx
import '../styles/globals.css'; // Assuming this is your global styles file
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import NextNProgress from 'nextjs-progressbar';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function Layout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <NextNProgress />
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </>
  );
}
```

In this example, the `NextNProgress` component is placed inside the `Layout` component, just before the `<html>` tag. This ensures that the progress bar will be rendered on every page that uses this layout.

Make sure you have installed the `nextjs-progressbar` package by running `npm install nextjs-progressbar`.

Now, you can use the `Layout` component as a wrapper around your pages or components in the following way:

```
import Layout from '../path/to/layout';

export default function MyPage() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {/* Your page content */}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

By doing this, the progress bar will be displayed at the top of the page whenever you navigate between routes in your Next.js application.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies.

Both of your answers in last hour appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.